# Removing Password from Sqlite Database

Tags: sqlite, .net-core

I went through the below document and encrypted my Sqlite Database using **.NET Core 3.1**.

[Encrypting Sqlite Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli)

I am able to change the password as in the document.

Now, I want to decrypt the database and **remove the Password**.

I used the below code and am not able to remove the Password.

```
using (SqliteConnection sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=UserData.db;Password=Password"))
{
    sqliteConnection.Open();
    var command = sqliteConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT quote($newPassword);";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$newPassword", DBNull.Value);        // "", null, (string)null, "NULL", DBNull.Value doesn't work.
    var quotedNewPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

    command.CommandText = "PRAGMA rekey = ''";
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Is there any tool like **DB Browser for SQLite** for viewing the encrypted Sqlite database (encrypted using .NET Core 3.1) ?

Comment: A work-around might be to dump the database.

Answer (score 1):

As the example uses SQLite Cipher then DB Browser for SQLite could open it as (if it is using SQLite Cipher 4.0.1 (not sure if this is backwards compatible)) per the **Important Notes** at [Version 3.11.0 released](https://sqlitebrowser.org/blog/version-3-11-0-released/).

Of course that requires the password/key as would anything. In short the database would be useless if encrypted and there were no password/key as nothing would be able to decrypt the data (assuming the level of security is unhackable). Hence why a password cannot be removed.

As for decrypting that is done as such when the database is opened *(I believe the file as a whole is encrypted and decrypted as part of closing/opening the database)*. Therefore you can copy the database as it's decrypted when it has been opened.

[VACUUM INTO](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) would be a simple way to accomplish this copy after the database has been opened.